# Conversion of Java Static to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, static

How Do I Perform this Type of conversion in Kotlin :

```
 public class DummyStatic {

    static String Aloha;

    static {

        if(true) {
          Aloha = "Hello";
        } else {
            Aloha= "Bye";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to complete this with Companion object and Object, but not able to achieve the required concept.

Answer (score 0):

Statics are represented in companion objects in Kotlin. The static initalizer logic goes into the `init{}` of the companion object

```
class DummyStatic {

companion object
    var Aloha: String

    init {
        if(true) {
          Aloha = "Hello";
        } else {
            Aloha= "Bye";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but try to convert with:) https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt

```
object DummyStatic {
  internal var Aloha:String
  init{
    if (true)
    {
      Aloha = "Hello"
    }
    else
    {
      Aloha = "Bye"
    }
  }
}
```